# Подсказки по местонахождению скрипта в VS Code

Tags: php, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

Как в VS Code сделать возможность по наведению курсором мыши на какую-либо функцию, объект , чтобы при этом как в sublime text выводилась подсказка о том в каком файле  определены данная функция или класс данного объекта, их изначальное местонахождение .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Должны быть установлены соответствующие `tools`(расширения), сам не пробовал но вот [vs php tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.PHPToolsforVisualStudio)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, по сути заработало !